# Ranged attack with touch range for powers like Blast

Tags: ranged-attack, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

I am confused about the use of a touch range for an attack (like Blast) that is ordinarily ranged. For instance, in the source book *Freedom's Most Wanted* (p. 100), the villain Sandstone has a power listed as "**Blast 12** (Cone Area [120 ft. wide]; Touch Range." Likewise, in *Villainous Archetypes 3* (p. 3) the Beast Lord has a power listed as "**Animal Control 11** (*Extras*: Area [Burst]; *Flaws*: Range 2 [Touch]."

My sense is that these area attacks (like a cone or burst) have the area range, but they must originate from the individual using the power. This differentiates between, for instance, the Magnetism Master and the Pyrokeneticist in *Instant Superheroes* (p. 26). The former has as an Alternate Power for his Magnetic Control as "**Blast 10** [*Extras:* Area (Burst)]," with no range qualifier, while the latter has "**Blast 10** [*Extras:* Area (Cone); *Flaws:* Range (Touch)." Presumably, the Magnetic Controller can center his area bast anywhere within range, while the Pyrokeneticist can only blast his cone of fire from his person outward at range. This would mean that the Pyrokeneticist's "**Blast 8** [*Extras:* Area (Explosion)]" with no qualifier would function sort of like a Fireball from D&D, and he can just launch a blast wherever he likes (within range) and then have it explode.

So far, so good. However, why do I not see the "Range (Touch)" qualifier on ordinary blast powers that obviously must originate from the attacker. For instance, in *Mutants and Masterminds*, their Battlesuite archetype (p. 17) has "**Blast 12** (force beams...)" with no qualifier. Why not? I am sure I am missing something, but I just don't know what.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

### A normal blast is just a ranged attack

Blasts are defined on p. 77:

> #### BLAST
>
> Effect: Attack
> Action: Standard
> Range: Ranged
> Duration: Instant
> Cost: 2 points per rank 
> Saving Throw: Toughness 
> You can make a damaging ranged attack. It might be a blast of energy, a projectile (arrow, bullet, throwing blade, etc.), or some similar effect. You make a ranged attack roll to hit the target. The attack’s damage equals your power rank.

That is, a normal blast has no area of effect, it just hits an individual target. The force beams the battlesuit fires are of this type, and while you fire them from your space, can hit a target anywhere within range.

The other examples you cite are different, in that they all have an "*Extras:* Area" feature of some kind, which means they shoot no normal blasts, but area blasts. Some of them can target the area anywhere, like you can a normal blast, but some others have the added flaw "Range: Touch" and can only do it emanating from your character.

Or said in another way: all ranged attacks in some form originate from you, but they usually do not feature a point of origin from which they spread an area, so there is no need to call that out. By default ranged area effects would have their point of origin anywhere in range you can attack, and express that this point is restricted to your person with the Range:Self flaw.

Comment: *Ultimate Power* clarified this by indicating that both Strike and Blast are Close and Ranged versions of the same power. One of the reasons for the odd notation, particularly the Animal Control being Flawed twice, is that Steve Kenson wanted all supplement books to work without having to buy additional books. Therefore, the changes in Ultimate Power are technically optional, and stat blocks for the other books are built using the core rule book.

Comment: "By default ranged area effects would have their point of origin anywhere in range you can attack."

This explains it. Thanks for the input.